# Maintaining Same CSS Layout

Tags: css, html

I have Javascript codes building a small div layer with CSS. The div layer has inline style codes to display the way I want. I notice the div layer looks distorted on some microsites. Are there ways to write the inline style code from being overwritten by other CSS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So, just so that I understand you correctly - you want the styles in a stylesheet to "overwrite" the inline styles?

Comment: hey marcus, no.. the inline style gets distorted for some reason. It looks like it's been overwritten

Answer (score 1):

Inline styling cannot be overwritten by a stylesheet. However, if there are properties in a stylesheet that aren't written inline, and therefore nothing is conflicting with one another, those styles will also be active.

The reason for distortion could be that other CSS files from these 'microsites' share similar naming conventions for this particular element. If this is the case, the stylesheets from these microsites are applying their styles that are otherwise unfounded within your inline styling.